# Undefined reference to method in parent class

Tags: c++, oop, undefined-reference

I ham having three classes in my program,

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {
    decompose();
  }
  virtual void decompose();
};

class B:public A {
private:
  int *b_data;
public:
  void decompose() {
    if (b_data != NULL) delete [] b_data;
  }
};

class C:public A {
private:
  int *c_data;

public:
  void decompose() {
    if (b_data != NULL) delete [] c_data;
  }
};
```

But when I compile this code with g++, I get the error:

```
In function `~A':
undefined reference to `vtable for A'
undefined reference to `A::decompose()'

In function `A':
undefined reference to `vtable for A'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
```

If it helps, class `A` is defined in a `.h` file and it's destructor is defined inline, and two other classes have two files `.h` and `.cpp`.

In my program I call these classes according to the following:

```
int main() {
  A *a;
  a = new B();  //constructor is defined
  delete a;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a problem with this code?

Comment: Are you using `g++` to compile?

Comment: I am using g++ and @lizusek I edited the question

Comment: There is no definition for `A::decompose`, did you intend to make it a pure virtual function?

Comment: @K-ballo I want this function to be defined in the children separately, so the function is declared in parent, and defined in children.

Comment: Search for pure virtual functions

Comment: @K-ballo That will not work because he is calling it in the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused due to a call to `A::decompose` in  **B** and **C** destructors. The `A::decompose` is called even if destructors are virtual and method is virtual itself. When **A** destructor is run for derived objects **B** or **C**, the derived part of the object was already destroyed.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void decompose() { std::cout << "A";}
  virtual ~A() {
    decompose();
  }
};

class B:public A {
private:
  int *b_data;
public:
  void decompose() {
      std::cout << "B";
    if (b_data != NULL) delete [] b_data;
  }
};

class C:public A {
private:
  int *c_data;
public:
  void decompose() {
      std::cout << "C";
    if (c_data != NULL) delete [] c_data;
  }
  ~C() {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B b;
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

AA

---

### Solution:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void decompose() = 0;
  virtual ~A() {
      std::cout << "~A";
  }
};
class B:public A {
private:
  int *b_data;
public:
  void decompose() {
      std::cout << "B_decompose"; if (b_data != NULL) delete [] b_data;
  }
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B";}
};

class C:public A {
private:
  int *c_data;
public:
  void decompose() {
      std::cout << "C_decompose"; if (c_data != NULL) delete [] c_data;
  }
  ~C() { std::cout << "~C";}
};
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       B b;
       C c;
        A* p = &b;
        p->decompose();
        p = &c;
        p->decompose();
        return 0;
    }
```

---

[compiled example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81dc933b4cb594d3)

[compiled example (solution)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5232991caf61ef2f)

Comment: But how can I call the destructor of `B` and `C` ?

Comment: @emab They are called. The problem is, calling decompose in ~A does not work properly. It just a rule of C++. You must work around it.

Comment: I can't use direct declarations of `B` and `C`, otherwise there was no problem and their destructor would be called immediately.

Comment: @NeilKirk I got your point, is there any way to call the destructors of children? (They are not called in my example)

Comment: @emab proper destructors are called by virtual dispatch, see my [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5232991caf61ef2f) given in answer

Answer (score 2):

Be careful calling virtual functions in constructors and destructors. They are not overriden as normal. `A(..)` and `~A()` ALWAYS call `A::decompose`. I think the compiler is complaining it cannot find this function.

Comment: The Standard text for this is [class.cdtor]#4 "When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the
call applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction, the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class."

Answer (score 1):

Create an implementation of your `A::decompose` function in your base class

```
virtual void decompose(){};
```

Comment: If it's empty, then what's the point of defining it? I used this to clean my memory and delete data structures.

Comment: Does it call the children's decompose either?

Comment: @emab The compiler doesn't know it's empty until you provide a definition that says "it's empty." There is no language rule that says "if a function is not implemented, then it defaults to empty."

Comment: So how should I call the children's destructor? The point in creating this `decompose` is to use it as the destructor of the children.

Comment: `decompose` is your destructor. Why not implement correctly your destructor instead?

Comment: Because the destructor of classes `B` and `C` are never called and instead, the destructor of class `A` is called which does not have access to private attributes of `B` and `C`.

Comment: @emab you will have to actually add a destructor to `B` and `C`, and call `decompose()` from each.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The destructors of `B` and `C` are not called at all. The reason for that is the way I create the instance of class.

Comment: Because `~A()` is virtual, when you delete through an `A *`, it calls `~C()` then `~B()`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Does it mean that there is no need to use decompose?

Comment: Yes, just make destructors and put the logic you currently have in `decompose` into the destructor.